# How to add set text programmatically one below another?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have set notification listener in my code. Whenever I receive a notification I want to put a Text view in my `linear layout` activity which has nothing initially.
 When second notification arrives I want to add one more text view below the previous text view.

```
public class InformationActivity extends Activity
{

    public static VideoInformationClass vidInfo = new VideoInformationClass() ;
    public static LinearLayout lv ;
    public static LayoutParams textViewParams;
    public static TextView tv ;
    public static TextView tv1,tv2,tv3,tv4,tv5,tv6,tv7,tv8,tv9,tv10;
    static int fieldFrequency;
    static int numberOfFrameLines;
    static int numberOfVisibleLines;
    static int numberOfVisiblePixels;
    static int interlace;
    static int imageFormat;
    static int videoCoding;
    static int scanType;

    VideoPropertiesParams GetParams;

    VideoPropertiesParams VP;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.information_activity);

        Context context = getBaseContext();
        LinearLayout lv = new LinearLayout(this);
        lv.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams textViewParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
       // tv = new TextView(this);


    }

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStart();
    onFieldFrequencyChanged();
    onImageFormatChanged();
    onInterlacedChanged();
    /*vidInfo.RegisterVidPropertyListener();
    vidInfo.RegisterSignalAndPresenceListener();
    vidInfo.RegisterThreeDChangeListener();*/
    if (ControlUnit.flag) {
    GetParams = vidInfo.GetVideoProperty();
    Log.i("TvPlayerFunctionalTestApp","Get Video Property called");
    fieldFrequency = GetParams.fieldFrequency;
    numberOfFrameLines = GetParams.numberOfFrameLines;
    numberOfVisibleLines = GetParams.numberOfVisibleLines;
    numberOfVisiblePixels = GetParams.numberOfVisiblePixels;
    interlace = GetParams.interlace;
    imageFormat = GetParams.imageFormat;
    videoCoding = GetParams.videoCoding;
    scanType = GetParams.scanType;
    }

   /* tv.setText("Something");
    tv.setLayoutParams(textViewParams);
    lv.addView( tv );*/
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStop();
    /*vidInfo.UnRegisterSignalAndPresenceListener();
    vidInfo.UnRegisterThreeDChangeListener();
    vidInfo.UnRegisterVidPropertyListener();*/
}
public void onFieldFrequencyChanged(){

    String info = "On field frequency changed , value is " + vidInfo.ChangedFrequency;

    tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setText(String.valueOf(info));
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams textViewParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    tv.setLayoutParams(textViewParams);
    lv.addView(tv);
}
public void onImageFormatChanged() {

    String info = "On Image Format  changed , value is " + vidInfo.ChangedFormat;
    tv1 = new TextView(this);
    tv1.setText(String.valueOf(info));
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams textViewParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    tv1.setLayoutParams(textViewParams);
    lv.addView(tv1 );
}
public void onInterlacedChanged() {

    String info = "On Interlaced  changed , value is " + vidInfo.InterlaceChange;
    tv.setText(String.valueOf(info));
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams textView
Params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    tv.setLayoutParams(textViewParams);
    lv.addView(tv);
}
```

Comment: Can you tell us what did you try?

Comment: String info = "On field frequency changed , value is " + vidInfo.ChangedFrequency;
 
tv = new TextView(this);            tv.setText(String.valueOf(info));
tv.setLayoutParams(InformationActivity.textViewParams);
lv.addView( InformationActivity.tv );

lv is my linear layout

Comment: Create a reference variable which increments with the notifications. make your linearlayout orientation vertical and add new textview by code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just declare your Linear layout with vertical orientation

```
       <LinearLayout
         android:id="@+id/linear"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
```

---

```
     LinearLayout lv = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linear);
      TextView tv = new TextView(this);

  tv.setLayoutParams(InformationActivity.textViewParams);
  tv.setText(String.valueOf(info));
  lv.addView(tv );//not InformationActivity.tv just write tv
```

It will automatically add next view below the the another

Comment: I want to add text programatically at run time.

Comment: To add another text , do i need to set tv1 = new TextView(this)?

Comment: I update is complete now u can check my ans .if it helps then vote up.
no need of creating tv1

Comment: @Szymon My upadate was not complete ,now u can check my answer.

Comment: @ShakeebShaheen That's ok, your initial edit looked exacly like my answer. No problem mate.

Comment: I have updated my full code . I get NullPointer exception lv.addView(tv);

Comment: @ShakeebAyaz, +1 for mentioning "_Just declare your Linear layout with vertical orientation_". It worked for me, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `LinearLayout` has orientation set to vertical. Then just add one more item:

```
LinearLayout layout = // your layout
TextView textView = // new text view
layout.addView(textView);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make a `Linear Layout` whose oreientation is vertacal and add `TextView` to it.

Answer (score 0):

You need a object from the main ViewGroup(RelativeLayout, LinearLayout etc.),

```
TextView text = new TextView(this);     RelativeLayout r = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(Id);r.add(text);
```

this lines of code will add a new textView object to the end of the r viewGroup.